# How To Make PHP Redirect URL with Base64

Tags: php, base64

For Example:

Base64 Encode:
www.google.com ---> d3d3Lmdvb2dsZS5jb20=

If access this link http://mptcs.com/external.php?url=d3d3Lmdvb2dsZS5jb20=
This link is base64 encode, redirect to www.google.com

How to make this script (Source Code) ../external.php?url=base64 ???

Thanks.

Comment: [header()](http://php.net/header) and [base64_decode](http://php.net/base64_decode)

Comment: i'm a newbie, i want to get a link source code for example???

Comment: best way to become a former newbie: start reading and coding. if you just want others to bang out or find code for you, you'll never be anything OTHER than a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base 64 url is: http://mptcs.com/external.php?url=d3d3Lmdvb2dsZS5jb20=

decode and redirection:

```
$url = base64_decode($_GET['url']);
header("Location: ".$url);
```